# Convert unicode to Python dict throws error

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, dictionary, unicode

I have android app which sends the SMS from the mobile app which is as shown below:

```
my_dict = {\
u'1': u'"sender" : "dz-080008", "text" : "enjoy 10%cashback@amazon.in &15%cashback@amazon app with hdfcbank debit/credit cards on min.purchase of rs5000 12aug-max amount rs1500 *t&c: bit.ly/1isljll", "time" : "1439212386383", "name" : "shyam"', \
u'0': u'"sender" : "am-swiggy", "text" : "please use this otp: 195830", "time" : "1439226026974", "name" : "shyam"', \
u'3': u'"sender" : "md-dgenie", "text" : "your dudegenie code is 6632. welcome to the world of dudegenie! your wish, my command!", "time" : "1439155803426", "name" : "shyam"', \
u'2': u'"sender" : "vx-611112", "text" : "we value your association with us. please call us on 89XXXXXXXX for exclusive offer onlyfor your number 88XXXXXXXX.u can reach us from 10:00 am-06:00 pm", "time" : "1439191024750", "name" : "shyam"',\
}.
```

But I couldn't process the request and store it in my database because the app would send 100 sms in single request and by the time I process that request by extracting the key value pair other request would have come. So to overcome this I did store the request as it as in my database in each row.Each row contains a string as shown below:

```
<QueryDict: {u'messages': [u'<QueryDict: {u\'10\': [u\'"sender" : "md-dgenie", "text" : "your dudegenie code is 6326. welcome to the world of dudegenie! your wish, my command!", "time" : "1439155575925", "name" : "p"\'], u\'1\': [u\'"sender" : "vm-olacab", "text" : "ola! your total bill for crn111085358 is rs 151. your invoice is on its way to your e-mail shyam.ns114@gmail.com. call us on 080-33553355 for any help.", "time" : "1439319374298", "name" : "p"\'], u\'0\': [u\'"sender" : "ad-hlpcht", "text" : "dear customer, 50% off on premium doorstep laundry. use the coupon code hc50. download the app now (bit.ly/help50chat) or give us a shout at 08039236390.", "time" : "1439356609276", "name" : "p"\'], u\'3\': [u\'"sender" : "vm-olacab", "text" : "say ola to your driver kiran m  (8711045873) for crn111085358. silver tata indica ka 51 a 3940  to pick you up @ 12:06 am, 12aug. please share https://www.olacabs.com/track/939u1pe0m with friends/family and let them track you. call 080-33553355 if you need help.", "time" : "1439318029414", "name" : "p"\'], u\'2\': [u\'"sender" : "vm-olacab", "text" : "ola! your cab has arrived on time. hop on to have an awesome experience with this ride!", "time" : "1439318244463", "name" : "p"\'], u\'5\': [u\'"sender" : "dm-020001", "text" : "get upto 40%off +extra rs150 off@nykaa freedom sale with hdfc bank debit/credit card. code: nykhdfc150 .min purchasers1500. validity 15thaug *t&c bit.ly/1wedi4r", "time" : "1439300971524", "name" : "p"\'], u\'4\': [u\'"sender" : "dm-044210", "text" : "1 week to go!top 400 breeze mobile web transactors to get inr 250* flipkart vouchers/week & ipad mini*t&c apply.start now on.sc.com/breezedownload-in stanchart", "time" : "1439303662943", "name" : "p"\'], u\'7\': [u\'"sender" : "dz-080008", "text" : "enjoy 10%cashback@amazon.in &15%cashback@amazon app with hdfcbank debit/credit cards on min.purchase of rs5000 till 12aug-max amount rs1500 *t&c: bit.ly/1isljll", "time" : "1439212386383", "name" : "p"\'], u\'6\': [u\'"sender" : "am-swiggy", "text" : "please use this otp: 195830", "time" : "1439226026974", "name" : "p"\'], u\'9\': [u\'"sender" : "md-dgenie", "text" : "your dudegenie code is 6632. welcome to the world of dudegenie! your wish, my command!", "time" : "1439155803426", "name" : "p"\'], u\'8\': [u\'"sender" : "vx-611112", "text" : "we value your association with us. please call us on 9739102435for exclusive offer onlyfor your number 889XXXXXXX .u can reach us from 10:00 am-06:00 pm", "time" : "1439191024750", "name" : "p"\']}>']}>
```

Now what is best way to unpack this kind of unicode/string.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings are almost in dictionary format, but are not surrounded by {}. I think you want '{"sender" : "am-swiggy", ...}'

Comment: I added those curly braces and it works. You have a sharp eye. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing something?  What are you trying to accomplish?  What is the goal of the jsondem and ast imports?

Is this not sufficient for what you are trying to do ?

```
import json

my_dict = {u'1': u'"sender" : "dz-080008", "text" : "enjoy 10%cashback@amazon.in &15%cashback@amazon app with hdfcbank debit/credit cards on min.purchase of rs5000 12aug-max amount rs1500 *t&c: bit.ly/1isljll", "time" : "1439212386383", "name" : "shyam"', u'0': u'"sender" : "am-swiggy", "text" : "please use this otp: 195830", "time" : "1439226026974", "name" : "shyam"', \
u'3': u'"sender" : "md-dgenie", "text" : "your dudegenie code is 6632. welcome to the world of dudegenie! your wish, my command!", "time" : "1439155803426", "name" : "shyam"', \
u'2': u'"sender" : "vx-611112", "text" : "we value your association with us. please call us on 89XXXXXXXX for exclusive offer onlyfor your number 88XXXXXXXX.u can reach us from 10:00 am-06:00 pm", "time" : "1439191024750", "name" : "shyam"',\
}

for i in my_dict.values():
    print json.dumps(i)
```

** output **

> "\"sender\" : \"dz-080008\", \"text\" : \"enjoy 10%cashback@amazon.in &15%cashback@amazon app with hdfcbank debit/credit cards on min.purchase of rs5000 12aug-max amount rs1500 *t&c: bit.ly/1isljll\", \"time\" : \"1439212386383\", \"name\" : \"shyam\""
>   "sender" : "dz-080008", "text" : "enjoy 10%cashback@amazon.in &15%cashback@amazon app with hdfcbank debit/credit cards on min.purchase of rs5000 12aug-max amount rs1500 *t&c: bit.ly/1isljll", "time" : "1439212386383", "name" : "shyam"
>   "\"sender\" : \"am-swiggy\", \"text\" : \"please use this otp: 195830\", \"time\" : \"1439226026974\", \"name\" : \"shyam\""
>   "sender" : "am-swiggy", "text" : "please use this otp: 195830", "time" : "1439226026974", "name" : "shyam"
>   "\"sender\" : \"md-dgenie\", \"text\" : \"your dudegenie code is 6632. welcome to the world of dudegenie! your wish, my command!\", \"time\" : \"1439155803426\", \"name\" : \"shyam\""
>   "sender" : "md-dgenie", "text" : "your dudegenie code is 6632. welcome to the world of dudegenie! your wish, my command!", "time" : "1439155803426", "name" : "shyam"
>   "\"sender\" : \"vx-611112\", \"text\" : \"we value your association with us. please call us on 89XXXXXXXX for exclusive offer onlyfor your number 88XXXXXXXX.u can reach us from 10:00 am-06:00 pm\", \"time\" : \"1439191024750\", \"name\" : \"shyam\""
>   "sender" : "vx-611112", "text" : "we value your association with us. please call us on 89XXXXXXXX for exclusive offer onlyfor your number 88XXXXXXXX.u can reach us from 10:00 am-06:00 pm", "time" : "1439191024750", "name" : "shyam"

Comment: No. That isn't enough. After I dump I need to parse and get back the corresponding key-value pair. After json.dumps I can't do that. Can I ?

Comment: @d-coder not really.  You do want a second dict then so adding the extra { will likely serve your needs.